# ssh config depending on interactive mode

Tags: bash, ssh, configuration

I've some rules in .ssh/config file which I would like activate only in interactive  mode (ie. terminal background change). Is that possible?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve? I suggest that you include the relevant parts of the two config files.

Comment: What's your definition of interactive? Do you mean whether a command has been passed to the `ssh` command or not? Or are you referring to the use of any of the flags `-t`, `-T`, `-N`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alias `ssh` if using a non-interactive shell as follows in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
    if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
        alias ssh='ssh -F ~/.ssh/config-non-interactive'
    fi
```

... then copy the non-interactive configuration you'd like to use to `~/.ssh/config-non-interactive` and you should be set.

Comment: When this is combined with `Include` I think it will be a flexible way of utilising config files. https://superuser.com/a/1142813 . There were many times I gave up on certain config features because it wasn’t compatible across my workstations.